# How to change span visibility based on table item property

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

Hi can somebody tell me if it is possible to set the visibility of a basic html element by using a property of the particular row item of the table it is contained within?

Here's some basic psuedo code to give yout some idea of what I'm trying to do.

```
foreach (var item in group) {
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span if(item.IsApprovedToSayHi) then style="display:none">Hi</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var item in group) {
var displayStyle = item.IsApprovedToSayHi?'display:none':'display:inline';
 '<tr>
    <td>
      <span then style='+displayStyle+'>Hi</span>'
```

Comment: it should work, depends what does for you "item.IsApprovedToSayHi"?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I prefer to do it -- or put a class on it and do it on page load (which may be annoying in some cases).

```
foreach (var item in group) {
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span <%: (item.IsApprovedToSayHi) ? " style=\"display: none;\" : string.Empty %>>Hi</span>
```

If you're using the Razor view engine, try this:

```
foreach (var item in group) {
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span @( item.IsApprovedToSayHi ? " style=\"display: none;\" : string.Empty )>Hi</span>
```

Comment: Are you using the Razor view engine? If so, the syntax is slightly different.

Comment: Added Razor version. If it still doesn't work, post a more complete example or at the very least an error message.

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach (var item in group) {
  <tr>
    <td>
      @if(item.IsApprovedToSayHi) {
         <span style="display:none">
      } else {
         <span>
      }
      Hi</span>
```